# filter PAM_yubico.so debug stdout

Tags: authentication, pam, yubikey

I want to use the yubico-pam module (https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-pam) to enable challenge-response authentification using my yubikey when sudoing. I've managed to do that by adding the line

> auth required     pam_yubico.so mode=challenge-response debug

to the file /etc/pam.d/sudo. However doing so give me a whole bunch of output when sudoing:

> [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(761)] called.
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(762)] flags 32768 argc 5
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(764)] argv[0]=mode=challenge-response
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(764)] argv[1]=debug
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(765)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(766)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(767)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(768)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(769)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(770)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(771)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(772)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(773)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(774)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(775)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(776)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(777)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(778)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(779)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(780)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(781)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(782)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(783)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:pam_sm_authenticate(823)] get user returned: ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:do_challenge_response(505)] Loading challenge from file ...
>   [util.c:load_chalresp_state(269)] ...
>   [pam_yubico.c:do_challenge_response(583)] Got the expected response, generating new challenge (63 bytes).
>   [pam_yubico.c:do_challenge_response(663)] Challenge-response success!

of which I only want to see the lines containing "do_challenge_response", to get some clear info when the authentication fails (eg. I forgot to insert my yubikey...).

How can I do this?
(eg. add "| grep 'do_challenge_response'" at the end of the line I added in /etc/pam.d/sudo, but that doesn't work)

Comment: check redirect stderr to stdout.   then grep should work.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Everything after pam_yubico.so seems to be passed as a parameter to pam_yubico.so. When I put

auth       required     pam_yubico.so mode=challenge-response debug 2&>1 | grep 'do_challenge_response'

in /etc/pam.d/sudo, I simply get output like this: 

[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(761)] called.
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(762)] flags 32768 argc 6
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(764)] argv[0]=mode=challenge-response
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(764)] argv[1]=debug
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(764)] argv[2]=2&>1
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(764)] argv[3]=|
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(764)] argv[4]=grep
...

Comment: It will of you do it right.

Comment: Then how should I do it? What should I put in /etc/pam.d/sudo instead of "auth required pam_yubico.so mode=challenge-response debug 2&>1 | grep 'do_challenge_response'" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passwordless login with Yubikey 5 NFC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167691/passwordless-login-with-yubikey-5-nfc)

Answer (score 0):

Use `auth required pam_yubico.so mode=challenge-response` **without** the `debug` at the end.

Comment: Agreed, but then I don't get any output at all (on failure nor on success). I still want some notification when something goes wrong, so I dont start thinking i mistypet my password